# PHP session not registered in a login page

Tags: php, session, authentication

I made a simple login and registration system, and I used sessions to display the username to the user, just for practice.
It all works fine in the registration page, and I can register users, but when I try to login, it displays a blank page, Instead of what it is supposed to do, which is displaying 'Login success' and redirecting me to 'index.php', setting my $_SESSION and in the 'index.php' I use the session to display information about the user.
The problem starts with that I'm not logged in after I insert the correct information in the form. This code worked great on my previous hosting service, but it had his problems.
This gets weirder when my friend can login to my account but I can't login.
So this is where is the 'Login success' part:

```
    else if ($login === true)
        {
            include 'include/aside.php';
            include 'include/footer.php';
            $id = id_from_username($username);
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            redirect('index.php','2'); // a replacement for header()
            echo 'Login Success.';
            exit();  
        }
```

Here is the check if the user is logged in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    return true;
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

This is the login query:

```
function login($username, $password) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = md5($password);
$loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1");
return (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) == 1);}
```

And yes, I use session_start(); at the start of each page.
I tried this with Mozilla firefox, Google chrome and IE6, none of them worked.
If you need more information, just tell me.

So why can't I login?

Thanks a lot.

(Oh, and excuse me for my english)

Comment: can you give details of redirect function?

Comment: You can try to include `ini_set('display_errors',1);` So that you will come to know the rea error.

Comment: @Udhay error below.
kewlashu, Here:

function redirect($url, $delay)
{
    header('Refresh:' . $delay . 'url=' . $url);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `include()` statements with `echo "success";`. This will let you know if the failure is in one of those files, or possibly with the file path / permissions.

Comment: It tells me that:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/shoham/domains/shohamh.voovq.com/public_html/core/init.php:2) in /home/shoham/domains/shohamh.voovq.com/public_html/core/init.php on line 3  


Line 3: session_start();

What does it mean?

Comment: Check that you don't have any spaces, tabs, or newlines before the `<?php` code.

Comment: Post your entire files to pastebin (including the includes). I'll find it!

Comment: The file `general.php` has a newline before `<?php`, but that might be an artefact of the way you posted them all together. The file `index.php` has new lines at the end of the first and second lines. Remove the `?>` and `<?php` where one follows the other.

Comment: That was because I wanted to space it out a bit, it's not like that on the server, but nvm, I found my first login page where it worked and it works now, Thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: So tell us, where was the error? Also, if this post was helpful then it is customary on SO to upvote. If the answer led to the resolution of the issue, then it is customary to accept (the green checkmark). Enjoy SO!

Comment: Well, there is a different problem now. I thought I was done, but it was a bug.
I'll write another question on it because it's totally different.